# Percentage deviation

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

**EDIT 1**

To clarify, why there is such a huge difference, the value of a subject can change and there were also new subjects in 2018 included which made some subjects of 2017 irrelevant.
So I think there are 2 things to analyse:

- how a constant subject changed over time
- how a subject which got changed, changed over time

at the moment I am mixing these 2 up... therefor i don't get any good data...

---

**EDIT 2:**

I thought this problem through again. I think I have to many "unstable" attributes in this data set.

- Value of the items changes
- new items and removed items
- count of sellers
- count of customers

all this attributes change every year. So the real question i have to answer first is, how to show a representative diagram with this data set.

If i can answer this question, i won't have the issue i described below.

---

I try to show a statistic where it displays the deviation of 2 values in 2017 and 2018.

For this i use the formula:

$$
\frac {(x-y)}{x} *(-1)=?\\
$$

a simple exampel:

$$
\frac {(20-50)}{20} *(-100)= 150\% \\
$$

so i see, there was a 150% increase. 
**Most of the data works just fine with this.**

Nevertheless I'm unsure in two cases.

- When 2018 has increased a lot
- When 2018 has decreased a lot

1.
$$
\frac {(20-18'000'000)}{20} *(-100) \approx 89'999'900\% \\
$$

2.
$$
\frac {(18'000'000-20)}{18'000'000} *(-100)\approx -99.9\% \\
$$

As you can see, my Problem is, the formula is at the moment not informative. I have no clue how to adjust the axis so that i can show this data any useful.
Did i made a mistake with my thinking process?

Comment: Why are you getting a positive answer for example 2.?

Comment: Notwithstanding your negative sign issue as posed by Minus One Twelfth above, there is nothing wrong with your calculation. It would be interesting to know what the *thing* is, i.e., what can increase from $20$ one year to $18,000,000$ the next?

Comment: sorry should be negative, my bad. i edited it.

Comment: In general, I think percentage change is not a useful way to compare two numbers that differ by a large fraction. I suggest you find a way to report the growth factor. So $500$ is $10$ times as large as $50$. The other way, $50$ is $1/10$ of $500$. This works when they are close too. $150$ is $1.5$ times as large as $100$.

Comment: @EthanBolker The problem is, there is a huge number of subjects which got no change and have a "stable" percentage. But the subject which got an update in value or an other attribute have extreme change... I think these are 2 separate problems which i have individually...

Comment: @808GroundState i updated the description, it occurs when there is a new subject or the value of the subject changes and it is not as popular anymore.

Comment: I think you should think through what you want your reader to get from the data and construct the narrative to help the reader along. Words (like the ones you have provided) may be more useful than trying to impose a particular way to quantify the changes.